# How to find out within rmarkdown document to which format it is being rendered?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Is there a way (method, global variable, option) to find out within an rmarkdown document to which format (pdf or html) it is being rendered?

Comment: The output type has to be specified in the YAML header under "output:"

Comment: @AllanCameron yes---and the same document may be knit to multiple formats, in which case you may need your code to do different things depending on the current output format. So you need a programmatic way for your code to know the output format.